# Show latest wiki post as of a particular date

Tags: mediawiki

Is there a query string or some similar method of automatically viewing the latest version of a page on a wiki as of a particular date?

Comment: That would very much depend on the flavor of software being used for the Wiki. What are you using?

Comment: The specific wiki I'm interested in doing this with is [Wowpedia](http://wowpedia.org). I'd like to only view pages as of a certain release.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are referring to a site running the standard wikipedia software...

In the top right of any article, you will find a **View History** link

[image: View History]

Click through that and you will find a history of each revision. If I wanted to look at the latest revision as of January 25, 2014, I would just scan down the page to find the latest entry on or before that date.

[image: Latest Rev As-Of]

Click the timestamp entry to view that revision of the article.

Comment: As of right now, this is what I am doing. However, doing this every time that I click a link becomes a hassle. I'd like a query string that I can add to the end of a URL to automatically do this.

Comment: So you want to go to a random article and for it to pull up the most recent revision as of a certain date of your choice, right? Unfortunately, revisions are indexed by id, not date.